# Delphi xe5 (FireMonkey) - Writing too slow to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey

I'm making an cross-platform application that should write values to a SQLite database. Right now it writes really slow and it freezes after a while. 
I'm calling this code each 10ms:

```pascal
SQLQueryInsert.SQL.Text := 'insert into task (id, latitude) values (:id, :lat)';
SQLQueryInsert.Prepared := true;
SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 1;
SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('latitude').AsFloat := 12332145;
SQLQueryInsert.ExecSQL();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using explicit transactions?

Comment: No, I don't use transactions. Is that possible in Delphi? In that case, how?

Comment: First, just set `Prepared` once, not every time the statement is going to execute. (The purpose of preparing the statement is to allow it to be compiled and cached for reuse; calling it every iteration defeats the entire purpose.) Second, it's impossible to help you find out why it's taking too long without seeing the actual SQL statement that is being run with `ExecSQL`. Seeing that it has two parameters is absolutely meaningless. Please [edit] to post the actual SQL.

Comment: Alright, I'll change that. I'm using insert into task (id, latitude) values (:id, :lat). Is an in memory table a possible solution?

Comment: Which version of SQLite? On which platforms? Try to [run it in exclusive mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) - see [this benchmark for instance](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/06/14/SQLite3-performance-in-Exclusive-file-locking-mode). That is, set the following pragma: `synchronous = OFF
locking_mode = Exclusive
page_size = 4096
journal_mode = WAL`

Comment: @user2432951 I have updated your question. Please check and edit if needed

Comment: Read again the first two sentences of my previous comment (you seem to have seen everything else except them). Set the SQL text, set `Prepared`, and **then** start your loop. Don't set `Prepared` again until you've changed the SQL statement to something totally different. (I explain why in my previous comment in the second sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

before you start, do this (create the vars ParamId and ParamLat in a suitable location)

```
SQLQueryInsert.SQL.Text := 'insert into task (id, latitude) values (:id, :lat)';
SQLQueryInsert.Prepared := true;
ParamId  := SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('id');
ParamLat := SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('latitude');
```

In the code you execute everytime:

```
ParamId.AsInteger := 1;
ParamLat.AsFloat  := 12332145;
SQLQueryInsert.ExecSQL();
```